# Slimmer Javascript Canvas Abstraction than Processing.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing.js, fabricjs

I am quite in love with the canvas element and the way [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) encapsulates it in a nice API. I am also familar to the regular [Processing](http://processing.org/) syntax. Processing.js includes an interpreter that enables you to execute regular Processing scripts within Processing.js. However, I prefer to use the plain Javascript syntax of Processing.js over the regular Java syntax. The minified version including the interpreter is 229 kb in size, the one which excludes the interpreter still 193 kb.

Can someone recommend another abstraction of canvas which is smaller in size, say 50 kb? Personally I think ~200 kb is too heavy for use in production.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) has a really low footprint (~76K minified, ~22K gzipped)

There is also [dojo.gfx](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/12/30/dive-into-dojo-gfx/) which has a nice abstraction layer and supports different renderers (SVG, canvas, VML, Silverlight).
I believe its bigger in filesize compared to fabric.js

Comment: We recently introduced lightweight `fabric.StaticCanvas`, which allowed to shave some size. There's still more savings possible, so expect even less size in a near future (~60-70KB for minimal distribution). For comparison, current jQuery is ~94KB (minified, not gzipped).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was searching for!